# Deriving Formula for internal and external angles of a concave polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons, angle

How to derive formula for internal and external angles of a concave polygon. The internet shows that the formula is same as a convex polygon, but how can we derive it? Thank You.

Comment: The usual approach is the same, regardless of convexity. Triangulate the polygon.

Comment: If the vertices of the polygon are $P_k$, consider vectors $V_k:=\vec{P_{k-1}P_k}$, and **instead of internal angles, work with deviation angles**, i.e., angles $\alpha_k$ between  $V_{k}$ and  $V_{k+1}$, with positive value in a convex site, and negative value on a concave site, and $\sum \alpha_k=2\pi$ (a complete turn when you have visited all the vertices).

Comment: "the internet shows that..." is like "I have heard that...". Could you give a **precise** reference in order to see if we are refering to the same thing...

Comment: @JeanMarie http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62228.html